# How to create an Exchange shell script that prompts for input

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I do a LOT of distribution list edits, and I have to show output that it was done to document completion as intended.
I am a powershell novice, so apologies if this is ridiculously easy.

what I would like is something that for this
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "*DL_Name*" | select Name, Primarysmtpaddress | sort name

So I can call it up and just paste in the DL name and get the output.

With one I can create many. for the other repetitive tasks.

Comment: `$dlname = Read-Host "Enter DL Name"; Get-DistributionGroupMember $dlname`. Just put that in a script file and run the script. There are other ways to provide input to code. I would just create a function if you want to just shorten the amount of code you have to type.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).